# frequent disconnects: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x3f0707

Tags: wifi, intel, iwlwifi

I keep getting disonnected and dmesg keeps repeating this,

```
wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from fc:ae:34:07:49:60 by local choice (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
wlp0s20f3: authenticate with fc:ae:34:07:49:60
wlp0s20f3: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
wlp0s20f3: Invalid HE elem, Disable HE
wlp0s20f3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
wlp0s20f3: send auth to fc:ae:34:07:49:60 (try 1/3)
wlp0s20f3: authenticated
wlp0s20f3: associate with fc:ae:34:07:49:60 (try 1/3)
wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from fc:ae:34:07:49:60 (capab=0x411 status=30 aid=17)
wlp0s20f3: fc:ae:34:07:49:60 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 292 TU (299 ms)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x3f0707
wlp0s20f3: associate with fc:ae:34:07:49:60 (try 2/3)
wlp0s20f3: associate with fc:ae:34:07:49:60 (try 3/3)
wlp0s20f3: association with fc:ae:34:07:49:60 timed out
wlp0s20f3: authenticate with fc:ae:34:07:49:60
wlp0s20f3: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
wlp0s20f3: Invalid HE elem, Disable HE
wlp0s20f3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
wlp0s20f3: send auth to fc:ae:34:07:49:60 (try 1/3)
wlp0s20f3: authenticated
wlp0s20f3: associate with fc:ae:34:07:49:60 (try 1/3)
wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from fc:ae:34:07:49:60 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=26)
wlp0s20f3: associated
```

I think this is the most important line, from `iwlwifi`,

> iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x3f0707

I also see this further up, not sure if it's related,

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode (-2)
firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-71.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-71.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-71.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-70.ucode (-2)
resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0xfedc0000-0xfedcdfff], which spans more than pnp 00:05 [mem 0xfedc0000-0xfedc7fff]
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-70.ucode (-2)
caller __uncore_imc_init_box+0xc1/0x100 [intel_uncore] mapping multiple BARs
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-70.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-69.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-69.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-69.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-68.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-68.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-68.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-67.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-67.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-67.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-65.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-65.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-65.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
```

What does this mean, how can I fix it? Currently using version `20210818-1` of iwlwifi.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by updating firmware, you can find more information on that here,

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721473/3285