# Where can I find the latest firmware for Linux?

Tags: debian, kernel, firmware, iwlwifi

According to dmesg, Debian's kernel is trying to load,

```
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
```

Currently, in `/usr/lib/firmware`, I see the latest version is

```
/usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
```

Where can I find version 72 of `iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0`? How come Debian packages a kernel that looks for it, when Debian doesn't ship it. Currently the latest version for [bookworm is here](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/firmware-iwlwifi). I can verify the latest version on the repo `20210818-1` with `apt-cache showpkg` and that there is an [open issue to update it](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1016058). Is there a way I can cut out the package manager and just do this myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the latest firmware in a `.tar.gz` format here,

- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/refs/

From there you can extract part or all of it to `/usr/lib/firmware`, after this it'll work fine,

```
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode (-2)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-71.ucode
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
```

There is a very short entry in the wiki [about this using `i915` as an example](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware#Firmware_missing_from_Debian)